# TypeScript and Vue2 (Nuxt2) Computed properties not being properly understood by Typescript compiler

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

First off I am definitely new to typescript and I am trying to get one of my employer's Nuxt2/Vue2 frontends on Typescript. But there is one problem I am having that I can't seem to find anywhere.

So traditionally in the script block of a Vue file, I would represent a computed property as follows.

```
<script>
    export default {
        computed: {
            arrayOfNumbers() {
                return [this.num1, this.num2]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And with this, I would be able to access it everywhere as a variable. Either in the script block with the this keyword or in the template block.

However, when I do the same following the nuxt ts documentation as follows.

```
<script lang="ts">
    export default {
        computed: {
            arrayOfNumbers(): number[] {
                return [this.num1, this.num2]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I then get an error due to the type of this computed property being recognized as a Method as Opposed to a variable of type number[]. Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case, as it appears to work fine? Its just strange that the typescript compiler is seeing this as wrong when I believe to have everything here configured correctly.
Heres the exact error:

```
  ERROR in pages/MyStats.vue:228:25
  TS2488: Type '() => number[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
  226 |         user_id: '',
  227 |       }
> 228 |       for (const number of this.arrayOfNumbers) {
```

My tsconfig is below if that is useful!

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2018",
      "module": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "lib": [
        "ESNext",
        "ESNext.AsyncIterable",
        "DOM",
        "dom.iterable"
      ],
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "~/*": [
          "./*"
        ],
        "@/*": [
          "./*"
        ]
      },
      "types": [
        "@types/node",
        "@nuxt/types",
        "@nuxtjs/axios",
        "@nuxtjs/auth-next",
        "@nuxt/vue-app"
      ]
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

Please let me know if I can help any further! Thanks!

Comment: I think this might just be an issue with vue2 in general, it's typescript support is lacking. What is going on is that the compiler is recognizing `this.arrayOfNumbers` as a function, hence the type `() => number[]` that can't be iterated.

Upgrading to Vue3 might be worth your time if you want proper typescript support (although imo, it's still lacking in the newest version).

Comment: Thanks @Tea_Lover_418 we definitely will move to 3 once nuxt 3 is out of RC!